# Excel Upload With multiple scenarios and validations

Tags: java

I need to develop code in Java which should able to perform following operations:

1) There is a new requirement in my application where user's will upload an excel sheet which would contain following fields.

country, threshold value, incremental value, start date and end date.
Basically this sheet will contail threshold values for each issuer country for a given date range. These date ranges are typically for a Quarter (but user can uplaod multiple sheets for diff. date ranges also.)

There are following multiple scenarios:

Lets say, user has uploaded first excel sheet for Germany for date range 01-Jan-2014 to 31-Mar-2014 with threshold value of 400 and incremental value of 10.
So I have designed one database table which will store the values in following columns.

issuerCountry, thresholdVal, IncrementalVal,start date, enddate and updated date.

2)Now, lets suppose user on some other day, again uploads an excel sheet for date range 10-Jan-2014 to 28-Jan-2014 with some different threshold value(say 200). Now following things should take place:

i) I need to amend previos entry in database with value 400 , to reflect start date and end date as 01-Jan-2014 and 09-Jan-2014 (which is 1 less than the 10-Jan-2014). This will be an update statement. Now I need to insert one record with threshold value as
200 and start date as 10-Jan-2014 and end date as 28-Jan-2014. And one more insert statement as 
with thresold value of 400 (which was uploaded first time) and start date as 29-Jan-2014 and end date as 31-Mar-2014.

So from above explanation: summary would be

Excel upload                 stardate       enddate        threshold value 
1 time                      01-Jan-2014    31-Jan-2014     400
2 time(10-Jan to 28-jan)    01-Jan-2014    09-Jan-2014     400  -- this should be update  statement  which changes 31st_Mar to 09-Mar
                         10-Jan-2014    28-Jan-2014     200 (this is the threshold value in second sheet) --this should be insert
                            29_Jan-2014    31-Mar-2014     400   -- this should also be insert

So whenever, new start and end dates comes through excel for a issuer country, I need to check existing records in database , and check whether new dates overlap with existing ones and if they are , need to perform above things. There can be multiple scenarios, like if 
in database we have two rows for a country, with start date and end dates as 1-Jan-2014 to 20_Jan-2014 and 21-Jan-2014 to 02-Feb-2014, and now new dates come as 12-Jan-2014 to 26-Jan-2014, then I need to change 20-Jan-2014 to 11-Jan-2014 and then insert one more record from 12-Jan-2104 to 26-Jan-2014 and one record with 27-Jan-2014 to 02-Fed-2014 and another one from 03-Feb-2014 to 31-Mar-2014.

This will get complicated as more dates overlap. Could you suggest some suitable solutions for such scenarios. I have to do a design presentation for this. Quick help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have tried until now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest you to get a copy of the latest Eclipse IDE with EMF included and start designing a model for your application. You can produce quite acceptable UML diagrams for your presentation by generating an ecore diagram.
As soon as you want to start programming you could generate the model (and much more), implement some business logic to get things done and create a RCP or RAP project to visualize your stuff.

Learn more about EMF:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/

[http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.htm](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMF/article.html)